# Binding a port to a host interface using the REST API

Tags: docker

The documentation for the commandline interface says the following:

> To bind a port of the container to a specific interface of the host
>   system, use the -p parameter of the docker run command:
>
> General syntax
>
> `docker run -p [([<host_interface>:[host_port]])|(<host_port>):]<container_port>[/udp] <image>`
>
> When no host interface is provided, the port is bound to
>   all available interfaces of the host machine (aka INADDR_ANY, or
>   0.0.0.0).When no host port is provided, one is dynamically allocated. The possible combinations of options for TCP port are the following

So I was wondering how I do the same but with the REST API?

With `POST /container/create` I tried:

- `"PortSpecs": ["5432:5432"]` this seems to expose the port but not bind it to the host interface.
- `"PortSpecs": ["5432"]` gives me the same result as the previous one.
- `"PortSpecs": ["0.0.0.0:5432:5432"]` this returns the error `Invalid hostPort: 0.0.0.0` which makes sense.

When I do `sudo docker ps` the container shows `5432/tcp` which should be `0.0.0.0:5432/tcp`.

Inspecting the container gives me the following:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.25",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "Bridge": "docker0",
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "5432/tcp": null
    }
}
```

Full inspect can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Enome/746f1bf1cbb2d15f9733).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is an undocumented feature. I found my answer on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/docker-user/port%2420redirection/docker-user/aHbNFACcTfs/nLY-oUihEAIJ):

When creating the container you have to set `ExposedPorts`:

```
"ExposedPorts": { "22/tcp": {} }
```

When starting your container you need to set `PortBindings`:

```
"PortBindings": { "22/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "11022" }] }
```

There already is an issue on [github](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/3039) about this.

Comment: thank you for your solution. that's useful for me but now i want to assign port number automatically by docker.io server. how can i do that by call it's Rest API?

Comment: `"ExposedPorts": { "22/tcp": {} }`
+
`"PortBindings": { "22/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "" }] }`

Will let docker auto-assign a host port.

Comment: Nice, any idea on how I could specify the host_interface using the API? I'd like to bind on 1.2.3.4:80 on my host for example. Can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Found the solution here: https://medium.com/@kevanahlquist/docker-remote-api-port-bindings-example-b55bc5194e20#.shz9s9hy0

Comment: @SethBrasile what does Docker do to "auto-assign a host port"? As in, does it hook it up the same port as the container? Does it pick the next available port?

Answer (score 20):

*Starting containers with PortBindings in the HostConfig was deprecated in v1.10 and removed in v1.12.*

*Both these configuration parameters should now be included when creating the container.*

```
POST /containers/create

{
    "Image": image_id,
    "ExposedPorts": {
        "22/tcp": {}
    },
    "HostConfig": {
        "PortBindings": { "22/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "" }] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't get my host to bind on any ports, and the problem was that I was running 1.12 and tried to specify the bindings at the "start" call. No errors or any unusual output, it just didn't work...

Comment: Pickel's solution didn't work for me but this did. I'm using the Hyper.sh API.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question had been answered, I using the above solution and here is how I did it in java using [Docker Java Client v3.2.5](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md)

```
    PortBinding portBinding = PortBinding.parse( hostPort + ":" + containerPort);
    HostConfig hostConfig = HostConfig.newHostConfig()
            .withPortBindings(portBinding);
    CreateContainerResponse container =
            dockerClient.createContainerCmd(imageName)
                    .withHostConfig(hostConfig)
                    .withExposedPorts(ExposedPort.parse(containerPort+"/tcp"))
                    .exec();
```