# docker remote api cannot bind a port to a host

Tags: python, docker

I was trying to use `docker`'s remote api to bind a host, but it always fails.

I pass this `dict` using python and `urllib2`:

```
{
    'Tty':True,
    'Volumes':[],
    'Image':'ubuntu',
    'Cmd':'',
    'WorkingDir':None,
    'Entrypoint':None,
    'Env':None,
    'AttachStdin':False,
    'AttachStdout':True,
    'AttachStderr':True,
    'OpenStdin':True,
    'ExposedPorts':{'80/tcp':{}},
    'HostConfig':{'PortBindings':{'80/tcp':['15080']}}
}
```

Then I use remote api to inspect container, it gives me the following:

```
"NetworkSettings":{
    "Bridge":"docker0",
    "Gateway":"172.17.42.1",
    "IPAddress":"172.17.0.48",
    "IPPrefixLen":16,
    "PortMapping":null,
    "Ports":{"22/tcp":null,"80/tcp":null}
}
```

I also tried to use the method in this link [Binding a port to a host interface using the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428302/binding-a-port-to-a-host-interface-using-the-rest-api),
but when I posted data to start the container, it will raise HTTP Error 500. So I guess whether the docker remote api had been changed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `PortBindings` parameter is slightly off. You're missing `"HostPort":`

Change it to:

```
'HostConfig':{'PortBindings':{'80/tcp':[{ "HostPort": '15080' }] }}
```

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.16/#create-a-container):

> - PortBindings - A map of exposed container ports and the host port they should map to. It should be specified in the form {
>     <port>/<protocol>: [{ "HostPort": "<port>" }] } Take note that port
>     is specified as a string and not an integer value.

Comment: Thanks, I added "HostPort" in my dict, I forgeted this in my question. Now I have found the error, it is not the docker's error, when i post data by using restclient, it is corret, so i think something is wrong in urllib2. Thanks a lot.:)